# Weighted kernel density estimate mapping in R

Tags: r, sf, sp

I am trying to reproduce ArcGIS' [kernel density](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/how-kernel-density-works.htm) in R. Specifically, I'd like to make a weighted kernel density map, like you see in Census OnTheMap ([example](https://secureservercdn.net/166.62.109.86/cb0.0c3.myftpupload.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/6.png)). I am running into a lot of dead ends, where you can easily make an unweighted density map, or you can easily plot a weighted density, but it's difficult to make a weighted density map.

The closest examples [use smoothing over a specified area](https://www.r-bloggers.com/kernel-spatial-smoothing-transforming-points-pattern-to-continuous-coverage/) or [expect you to already have a raster set up](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/150141/r-spatial-kernel-density-estimation). I'm new to raster, so it's difficult to make sense.

I do know that ArcGIS defaults the bandwidth to Silverman's rule of thumb (`bw.nrd0`).

So how do we take points (say polygon centroids) with a value and make a map plotting the density of those values?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `sp.kde` function in the spatialEco package for a weighted or "unweighted" kernel density estimate (KDE). However, a kde on polygon centroids is not valid because the polygon sets represent areas of various sizes.